# Azure app service view has not been precompiled errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, azure-web-app-service

We have a multi instance Azure appservice that's hosting an IIS .net MVC application, with precompiled views.
Every once in a while we start getting these errors(worth mentioning that not at deploy), that our views are not precompiled.
The errors starts spreading in time to all views making our instance unstable and not being able to serve any requests.
We initially suspected a third party javascript rendering dll that was not properly recycled and locks were not released but we removed it and the issue is still there.
While investigating further it seems that our issues happen when IIS scales up/down app domains, as part of internal resource management routines however we still couldn't get to the bottom of this.

One exception if it helps for anything:

```
    The file '/Views/MakeModelYear/_Tooltip.cshtml' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested. at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Search_Results_cshtml.<Execute>b__3()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass42_0.<RenderSection>b__0(TextWriter tw)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<RenderPageCore>b__0(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

There are some optimizations done like azure cache enabled to spare us from transient storage issues.

Comment: If your web.config contains any assemblies like this and deployed server doesnot contain these assembiles in bin or GAC, then this error will occur.

Comment: The problems appear after startup not during deploy. If assemblies where missing this error would appear instantly upon accessing the specific view. However the issue appears after a while and seems to correlate with other instances starting in the background(on azure upgrades)

Comment: @Tavi did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: No, we decided to disable precompile views for now untill we manage to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Wanted to add that we have had a similar issue that doesn't happen all the time which makes it all the more difficult to track down. We're on Azure App Service (Asp.net MVC) and we also pre-compile our razor views. We deploy to a slot and then swap the slot. Occasionally, our site will stop receiving requests after about two hours from when we deployed. No resolution as of yet.

Comment: We've faced with same issue. Has anyone solved it?

Answer (score 0):

We have had a similar issue, resulting in the same symptoms. 
A site is working fine after publishing, then pages that have been working fine suddenly start to error with the message that you included above. 
You could test to ensure that your server's antivirus is not the culprit. We considered adding the web site and 'Temporary Dot Net Files' to the AV console's list of 'folders to exclude', but clearly there is risk involved in doing that. 
We also removed any files that were not required from the bin folder, such as a couple of backup zip files.